# How can a god that loses its memories in becoming mortal, regain them?

Tags: alternate-worlds, gods

God looked down at his creation, humanity, and was disgusted with what it saw. The race had become so entrenched in hypocrisy and sin that it considered destroying it. However, evil abominations from beyond the Veil had snuck pass the plane barrier to introduce more chaos unto the planet. Realizing that he may still love humans, he set about coming up with a plan to save them.

The barrier that separates the mortal from the Astral Plane prevent God from affecting reality. The only way around this is to reincarnate himself as a mortal. It sent a piece of himself to be born on the Mortal Plane to grow up as a human male. This human would save humanity from itself and rally it against these outside forces.

However, there is a slight hiccup. The stress of the reincarnation caused by passing through the barrier caused the mortal to forget his memories of being a god. While he does understand that he has powers and abilities that others don't, he remains ignorant of his divine, godly heritage, and of his mission.

How can this mortal incarnation of a deity regain its memories?

Comment: Seems a slightly ill-specified question. Sending information across in the form of "a piece of himself" works fine, information across in the form of memories, not fine? What is the "piece of himself"? Why is it OK to send matter and/or information across the barrier, but other actions don't work? Seems like this is entirely story based magic, and you get to wave your hands as you see fit.

Comment: Just a minor note - while I have seen you ask quite a lot of **very** good/interesting questions (and can see the outline of a couple of worlds being built up in them), I also see that you've only issued [1 green tick](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/136208/how-can-a-mortal-woman-successfully-carry-a-demigod-to-term) for [273 questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52361/incognito?tab=questions).  If people aren't getting any feedback about the sort of answers that you are looking for, they *might* stop answering...

Comment: @Chronocidal got it.

Comment: this entirely depends on how gods and powers work in your story.

Comment: This question popped on top of the list, hence I'm reviewing it. I am not sure how can this be answered reasonably with so few details on the magic, or is it about making our own rule to pass the memories on? Either way it doesn't really fit WB:SE today standards, either lacking a goal to evaluate answers with or details to avoid being opinion-based. More likely the first.

Comment: I really don't think this one is answerable beyond "you tell us." The nature of a heaven/earth interface is essentially the world's magic system. All rules are your rules. You're asking for "hard magic" rules while you're still in "soft magic" story telling mode. This comes up enough that there's a https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GodInHumanForm page that covers it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe he had written something down and sent it to Earth beforehand? Or maybe someone with clairvoyance predict him and spread the word?

(I'm sorry, I'm very new at this)

Comment: "Found his old lab notebooks" was going to be my answer.  Or he could do like that amnesiac dude in the movie Memento and tattoo "YOU ARE GOD!" somewhere on his body.

Comment: @Willk Or put his future face into Toast all over the world.  Set up a large, highly visible astronomical event at his birth to make people realise he's special?  Announce his impending birth to some rich prophets, who can come visit him with gifts and capital to kick-start his life?

Answer (score 2):

## Some demons are just plain stupid

> ... evil abominations from beyond the veil had snuck pass the plane barrier

Your "evil abominations" see your incarnated deity and freak out, talking to him.  Let's see another incarnation story: the Bible.  First, from Mark 5:

> [When the man with the demon saw] Jesus from a distance, he ran up and bowed down before Him; 7 and shouting with a loud voice, he *said, "What business do we have with each other, Jesus, Son of the Most High God? I implore You by God, do not torment me!"

And from Luke 4:

> While the sun was setting, all those who had any who were sick with various diseases brought them to Him; and laying His hands on each one of them, He was healing them. Demons also were coming out of many, shouting, "You are the Son of God!"

Well, so much for keeping things on the DL!  Maybe your deity could figure out that he can heal people, and when he starts healing or casting out demons they come out shouting something similar.  If the reincarnation didn't know he was the reincarnation, a bunch of demons letting the cat out of the bag would make him start to suspect at least.

Furthermore, some demons might see him and shout *"I know why you're here!  You'll never be able to stop us!"*  Oh, so I was sent here to stop you? Got it, thanks!

It may seem a little silly at first, but who said that "evil abominations" were well-organized, intelligent, and not at all prone to oversharing?

## Torture the evil abominations

Your reincarnation might torture them, interrogate them, or otherwise extract this information from them through trickery, bribery, or the like.  Again, the demons probably know what's up, so they're the ones who will end up giving out the details!

Comment: Would He still torment them if they implored him "I implore You by God, do not torment me?".  Does that work?

Comment: @Willk I don't know - it's your story!  Maybe that compels the reincarnation, maybe it doesn't.  That's a fascinating concept I'd encourage you to explore.

Comment: @Willk "Don't torture us for info God!" I'm not God but thanks for the idea since you seem to be afraid of that!

Answer (score 0):

*How can this mortal/deity regain it's memories?*

**Pray to HIMSELF.**

Would cause a niiiice echo when he says the words of **Pater Noster**.

Answer (score 0):

He dies. Upon death he can access the godmind that doesn't fit in his fleshbrain, and with his godpower can resurrect himself with knowledge intact.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods they can use to communicate.

## Learn the demonic arts and breach the astral plane back wherever they came from.

The issue is, I presume, that the veil or astral plane blocks entry into reality.

Then you can directly regain your memories from god. The evil beings however were able to sneak past the barrier from somewhere. Go there and god can communicate to you with no barrier. You may have to destroy a lot of abominations, but that's no issue for you with your powers.

## Have god repeatedly incarnate people to send a message.

God can incarnate himself once. Why not again? These ones don't need full divine powers. Try sending through hundreds or thousands of lesser gods. See if any can send a message as a prophet, and if that fails send them as a code.

You can adjust this for your world, but here is a basic method.

1. See if you can send them with a message. If you can grant them super powers, why can't you grant them very specific super powers, like the power to give the messiah specific memories, or a book from you? Can you give them a particular appearance, like a tattoo that explains everything?
2. You can force them to reincarnate at particular times which leaves a coded message.
3. You could pick a family which believes that they are there to kill all demons, and incarnate a new fully powered child among them. You can see the entire world so you can pick a candidate carefully.
4. Can you make lesser beings like angels or mortal souls incarnate with particular messages?

Answer (score 0):

## because of simple nature

Gods are vast being that are impossible to understand for mere mortals. We already have trouble with countable and uncountable infinity in mathematics. How can we understand the full picture?

The god can send (part of) itself onto the mortal plane for reincarnation. That means the god grows up like any mortal, with all it's limitations. Sure the god will make the avatar as best it can. DNA that helps with strength, stamina, intelligence and a whole lot. It also includes knowledge that it is born with or grows into, like horses able to walk from birth or teenagers growing a basic instinct how sex works. This way the god can give itself a great set of (instinctive) knowledge.

The barrier obviously also lets some part of the gods power through, or it couldn't reincarnate. So this instinctive knowledge can aid it in understanding the powers. In time it can aid in understanding where the devine powers come from, as well as allowing enough of this godly power and knowledge through to regain enough relevant memories.

In summary, a diety can regain it's memories in mortal form because of instinctive knowledge and regaining them slowly through the barrier.